# Including a class in an inherited class in python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, houndify

I'm trying to integrate Jasper(https://github.com/jasperproject/jasper-client) with houndify python sdk. I'm trying to integrate the Houndify in Jasper's Speech to Text engine(https://github.com/jasperproject/jasper-client/blob/master/client/stt.py).

The problem is all the stt engines are defined as inherited class of an abstract class and I need to define an inherited class for Houdify. 
 The transcribe() method returns the transcribbed text, but the Houndify uses a  class to return the text.

So how can I include a class(Houndify transcribe class) within a method of inherited class(Houdify stt class) such that the value returned by the class(Houndify transcribe class) should be returned by the method of inherited class?

**Code to integrate:**

```
import wave
import houndify
import sys
import time

# The code below will demonstrate how to use streaming audio through Hound
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # We'll accept WAV files but it should be straightforward to 
  # use samples from a microphone or other source

  BUFFER_SIZE = 512


  CLIENT_ID = 
  CLIENT_KEY = 

  #
  # Simplest HoundListener; just print out what we receive.
  #
  # You can use these callbacks to interact with your UI.
  #
  class MyListener(houndify.HoundListener):
    def onFinalResponse(self, response):
      transcribed = response['AllResults']
      print "\n"
      print transcribed[0]['FormattedTranscription']
    def onError(self, err):
      print "Error: " + str(err)

  client = houndify.StreamingHoundClient(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_KEY, "test_user")

  fname = 'whatistheweatherthere.wav'
  audio = wave.open(fname)
  client.setSampleRate(audio.getframerate())
  samples = audio.readframes(BUFFER_SIZE)
  finished = False

  client.start(MyListener())
  while not finished:
    finished = client.fill(samples)
    samples = audio.readframes(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if len(samples) == 0:
      break
  client.finish()
```

**Code where to be integrated:**
The above stt.py